# GitHub desktop - Error : please tell me who you are

Tags: github

[image: Ошибка]
После установки git , декстоп версия перестала работать и запрашивает авторизацию, в настройках почту изменить не дает,через git конфиг тоже никакого результата, как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Открыть файл `.git/config` в любом текстовом редакторе и поправить строчки

```
[user]
    name = Traums
    email = email@example.com
```